# How can I change the caption for the Heatmap as the method takes no arguments?

Tags: seaborn, data-science, eda

I plotted a graph and would like to change the title but I don't see any parameter for this:

code:

```
klib.corr_plot(df)
```

[image]

I need to change the caption which is fixed at 'Feature-correlation (pearson)'

Answer (score 1):

Catch the axes object and use the `set_title` method:

```
ax = klib.corr_plot(df)
ax.set_title('new title')
```